# angularJS services - return promise for retrieving data AND object for managing data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question regarding angularJS services.

From what I have read, there are two ways of using services.

[1] Have a service return a promise to return data. If you use this method, in your routeProvider, you can make sure Angular resolves this promise to return data BEFORE it loads the page.

e.g.

```
App.factory('BooksService', function($q, $http) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/rest/books').then(function(data) {
     deferred.resolve(data);
  }, function(err) {
     deferred.reject(data);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Then, in my route provider:

```
...
  $routeProvider.when('/books', {
    controller : 'BooksCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/books.html',
    resolve: {
       books: 'BooksService'
    }
  });
...
```

Then, in my controller:

```
App.controller('AddPaypalAccountCtrl', function($scope, BooksService) {
    $scope.books = BooksService;
}
```

[2] Have a service return an object that contains functions and data.

e.g.

```
App.factory('BooksService', function($q, $http) {
  var books = [];
  var service = {
      getBooks : function() {
         return books;
      },
      addBook: function(book) {
         books.push(book);
      }
  };
  return service;
};
```

My question: Is it possible to get the best of both worlds and have a service return a promise that when resolves returns an object that contains functions and data?

I want the $http call to get the books to be resolved before I load the '/books' page, BUT I also want access to a service that can manage said books. Of course I can write two separate services, but I wonder if it's more efficient to keep them both in the same service and write a service that kills two birds with one stone like so:

Here's an example of my factory that returns a promise for retrieving the books.

```
App.factory('BooksService', function($q, $http) {
  var books = [];
  var service = {
     getBooks: function() {
         return books;
     },
     addBook: function(book) {
         books.push(book);
     }
  }
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/books').then(function(data) {
     books = data.data;
     deferred.resolve(service);
  , function(err){ 
     deferred.reject(err);
  });
  return service;
};
```

Then, as per before, my route provider is as follows, requiring that books be retrieved before I go to the /books page:

```
...
  $routeProvider.when('/books', {
    controller : 'BooksCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/partials/books.html',
    resolve: {
       books: 'BooksService'
    }
  });
...
```

Then, in my controller, I will attach books to the scope like so.

```
App.controller('AddPaypalAccountCtrl', function($scope, BooksService) {
    $scope.books = BooksService.getBooks();
}
```

I haven't seen anyone do this yet, so I'm wondering if this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are trying to break the SRP - Single Responsibility Principle.

What is the Responsibility of your service? 
Provide an API for async request or make the request?
If it provides API, it should not be loaded async.
If too make the request, it should be a method of the service, not the service itself. A service is the *interface* to your request, not the request!

Rarely you may need to get logic back from your server, but again, you have to separate concerns:

- Get the logic (e.g. Angular expression as a string) from server.
- Parse into a function performing the logic (can be done with Angular `$parse` service).
- Inject your logic function wherever you need to use it.